# gulp cannot find module '@babel/core'

Tags: gulp, babeljs, babel-core

I'm trying to build environment using `sudo gulp` that raised this error:

```
[14:22:36] 'scripts' errored after 12 ms
[14:22:36] Error: Cannot find module '@babel/core'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/armory_frontend/node_modules/gulp-babel/index.js:7:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
```

It seems i have dependencies issues, so I'm adding my `package.json` file:

```
{
      "private": true,
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=4"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "amd-optimize": "^0.6.1",
        "babel-cli": ">=6.24.1",
        "babel-core": ">=6.4.0",
        "babel-preset-env": ">=1.0.0",
        "babel-preset-stage-2": ">=0.0.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-register": ">=6.5.2",
        "browser-sync": ">=2.2.1",
        "chai": ">=3.5.0",
        "del": ">=1.1.1",
        "gulp": ">=3.9.0",
        "gulp-autoprefixer": ">=3.1.0",
        "gulp-babel": ">=6.1.1",
        "gulp-cache": ">=0.4.2",
        "gulp-concat": ">=2.6.0",
        "gulp-cssnano": ">=2.0.0",
        "gulp-eslint": ">=2.0.0",
        "gulp-filter": ">=4.0.0",
        "gulp-flatten": ">=0.3.0",
        "gulp-htmlmin": ">=1.3.0",
        "gulp-if": ">=2.0.0",
        "gulp-imagemin": ">=2.2.1",
        "gulp-load-plugins": ">=0.10.0",
        "gulp-path": ">=3.0.3",
        "gulp-plumber": ">=1.0.1",
        "gulp-react": "^3.1.0",
        "gulp-sass": ">=2.0.0",
        "gulp-size": ">=1.2.1",
        "gulp-sourcemaps": ">=1.5.0",
        "gulp-uglify": ">=1.1.0",
        "gulp-uglify-es": ">=1.0.0",
        "gulp-useref": ">=3.0.0",
        "gulp-util": ">=3.0.7",
        "pump": ">=1.0.0",
        "main-bower-files": ">=2.5.0",
        "mocha": ">=2.5.3",
        "uglify-es": ">=1.0.0",
        "wiredep": ">=2.2.2"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "env": {
          "es6": true,
          "node": true,
          "browser": true
        },
        "rules": {
          "quotes": [
            2,
            "single"
          ]
        }
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
        "babelify": "^7.3.0",
        "bootstrap": "=4.0.0-alpha.6",
        "browserify": "^14.4.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.1.0",
        "fancybox-plus": "^1.3.8",
        "flag-icon-css": ">=2.7.0",
        "font-awesome": ">=4.6.3",
        "gulp-notify": "^3.0.0",
        "jquery.easing": "^1.4.1",
        "json2csv": ">=3.7.3",
        "jsx": "^0.9.89",
        "modernizr": ">=3.0.0",
        "nprogress": ">=0.2.0",
        "open-sans-fontface": ">=1.4.0",
        "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
        "react": "^15.6.1",
        "react-circular-progressbar": "^0.5.0",
        "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
        "react-edit-inline": "^1.0.8",
        "resemblejs": ">=2.2.3",
        "tether": ">=1.3.2",
        "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
        "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
        "ws": "^3.2.0"
      }
    }
```

I have read that there is issue with babel that there are change the module name to `@babel/core` from `babel-core`
should it make difference with my current configuration?

Which of my packages trying to use the new `@babel/core` ?

Comment: So you know, it's an extremely bad idea to use `>=` for things like this. Node's ecosystem is specifically build around the ideal that any `2.x` version is compatible and safe up upgrade, but upgrading to `3.x` may break things. By using `>=` with no paired upper bound, you are stating that you expect _any_ future version to be compatible, which is not the case. This is why `^` exists, like in your `gulp-react` example.

Comment: Which fields are problematic here?

Comment: You should only every use `>=` with an upper bound, like `>=4.2 <5` or something, but that is identical to `^4.2`, which is why using `^` is always recommended. Almost every dependency you have is using `>=`, which means your code is going to break very often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just add `@babel/core` to your `"devDependencies"`

like that:

`"@babel/core": "^7.0.0",`